# GetX RouteManagement Get.offAll() & Get.ofAllNamed() showing null check operator was on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, null, navigation, flutter-getx

## I have faced this error

The following CastError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: HomeState#4dd52):
https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/errors

### We have all dependency on flutter

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

Flutter 2.10.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision c860cba910 (8 weeks ago) • 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
Engine • revision 57d3bac3dd
Tools • Dart 2.16.2 • DevTools 2.9.2

Comment: Did you change your `MaterialApp` to `GetMaterialApp`?

Comment: Yes i am already using the GetMaterialApp. @S.M.JAHANGIR